Docker Compose: Mounted Volume Permissions Issue (root:root despite multiple configurations)
Question:
I am facing a permission issue with Docker Compose on a mounted volume where I can't assign the correct permissions from the host to the container. The mounted directory always results in root:root permissions inside the container, despite several attempts to enforce the correct ownership. Below are the complete details of my configuration and the attempts I've made.
Context:

I am working on Ubuntu.
I have a Laravel project containerized using Docker Compose, which includes several containers: php, nginx, composer, node.
I need to mount a directory called project, which is on the host, inside the php container at /var/www/main/project.
I am trying to ensure that the mounted volume has the same user (user@zg.local) and group (domain users@zg.local) permissions as on the host.
The main problem is that every time the volume is mounted, it results in root:root permissions inside the container, causing errors when Laravel tries to write into this directory.

Current Configuration (docker-compose.yaml):
docker-compose.yaml
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID}
        GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID}
    user: "${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID}"
    privileged: true
    command: |
      bash -c "
        mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/logs &&
        mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework/{sessions,views,cache} &&
        mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/app/public &&
        chown -R ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} /var/www/main/project &&
        chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/storage &&
        php-fpm
      "
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - laravel_storage:/var/www/html/storage
      - laravel_cache:/var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
      - ../vb-crs:/var/www/main/project:rw,shared
    networks:
      - laravel_net
    environment:
      TMPDIR: /var/www/html/tmp
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

volumes:
  laravel_storage:
    driver: local
  laravel_cache:
    driver: local

networks:
  laravel_net:
    driver: bridge

Current Configuration (dockerfiles/php/Dockerfile):
FROM php:8.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libxml2-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install dom pdo pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

COPY ./xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

# Crea il gruppo e l'utente con i tuoi ID
ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

# Usa nomi semplici per il sistema ma mantieni gli ID corretti
RUN groupadd -g ${GROUP_ID} appgroup && \
    useradd -u ${USER_ID} -g ${GROUP_ID} -m appuser


# Crea tutte le directory necessarie per Laravel
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework/sessions \
    && mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework/views \
    && mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework/cache \
    && mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/logs \
    && mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/app/public \
    && mkdir -p /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache \
    && chown -R appuser:appgroup /var/www/html \
    && chmod -R 775 /var/www/html

# Configura PHP-FPM
RUN sed -i "s/user = www-data/user = appuser/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf && \
    sed -i "s/group = www-data/group = appgroup/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

USER appuser

WORKDIR /var/www/html

Problem:
Despite the various attempts, when I enter the container with docker-compose exec php bash and check the permissions with ls -la /var/www/main/project, I always see root:root as the owner of the mounted directory. This results in an error when Laravel tries to create files or directories in that path.
Example of the error:
Failed to create router structure: file_put_contents(/var/www/main/project/home/web/[redacted]/router/chain/[redacted]/test.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Attempts Made:

Run the Container with the Same UID and GID as the Host:

I used the .env file to pass the USER_ID and GROUP_ID values.
Added user: "${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID}" to docker-compose.yaml.
Passed USER_ID and GROUP_ID as build arguments in the Dockerfile to create a user with those IDs.
Result: The permissions of the project volume still remain root:root.


Use the privileged Flag:

I added privileged: true to the PHP container to ensure the container has root access and can change the mounted volume permissions.
Result: No change. Permissions remain root:root.


chown Command at Container Startup:

In the startup command (command), I added chown -R ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} /var/www/main/project to change the permissions of the mounted volume immediately after the container starts.
Result: Again, permissions remain root:root.


Mount Propagation (:shared):

I tried adding :rw,shared to the mounted volume to ensure that permission changes are propagated between the host and the container.
Result: Permissions did not change.


Additional Checks:

I ran ls -la both on the host and inside the container, confirming that the directory on the host has the correct users@zg.local:domain users@zg.local user and group.



Question:
How can I ensure that the mounted volume ../project has the correct user and group permissions inside the Docker container? Is there something I'm missing in the current configuration? Or is there another approach I could try to resolve this permission issue?
Thank you in advance for any suggestions!
